# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)! +n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to compute the nature of this series, and if it converges, the sum of it. I just can't find the proper way to get to the partial form, from where I can simplify the parts. I've tried writing $(n+1)!+n!$ as $(n-1)!(1+n)$, but that didn't work either.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!+n!}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost there. Observe that

$$\frac 1{(n-1)!+n!} = \frac 1{(n-1)!(n+1)} = \frac n{(n+1)!} = \frac {n+1}{(n+1)!} - \frac 1{(n+1)!} = \frac1{n!} - \frac1{(n+1)!}$$

Do you see how it telescopes?

Comment: Damn, thank you, I haven't thought about multiplying with n both the N and D. I should be getting more creative. :)

Comment: Sometimes it could be hard to figure out telescoping sums. Write out the first few partial sums $(\frac12, \frac56, \frac{23}{24}, \frac {119}{120}, \dots)$ and see if a pattern emerges.