# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!+n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

$$\text{Calculate } \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!+n!}$$

I'm having a hard time solving this. I now I must create a minus to transform it into a telescopic series but I've been staring at it for a long time and do not see where the minus is supposed to appear. I suppose I probably need to group $n!$ and $(n-1)!$ as $((n-1)!)(1+n)$ but, again, I still do not know what to do with the numerator. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)! +n!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911118/sum-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-1-n) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(n-1)!%2Bn!%7D%24)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

For $n(n+1)\ne0,$

$$\dfrac1{(n-1)!+n!}=\dfrac1{(n-1)!(1+n)}=\dfrac n{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{n+1-1}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac1{n!}-\dfrac1{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: It's a duplicate (easy to find with Approach0).

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for finding that. I have also voted for closure