Factorial series in the denominator
Hi I have a factorial series and I don't know how to solve it:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k-1)!+k!}$$
If I replace it with numbers I get:
$$\frac{1}{0!+1!}+\frac{1}{1!+2!}+\frac{1}{2!+3!}+\frac{1}{3!+4!}+...+\frac{1}{(n-1)!+n!}$$=
$$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{30}+.......+\frac{1}{(n-1)!+n!}$$
=
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$$ ?????
How did it reach this conclusion?Can I get a hint?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3911118/42969

@YvesDaoust where does (k-1)!k come from?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!+k!}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{1}{1+k}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{1}{1+k}\frac{k}{k}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}.
$$

where does $$\frac{1}{1+k}$$  and $$\frac{k}{k}$$ come from???

Note the $k!=(k-1)!k$. Then, you get out the common factor $(k-1)!$. $k/k=1$ and does not change the equation.
